# Trouble with chat layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to replicate a chat layout on a site I am working on. I was able to create the chat bubble and get the content in pretty much the right spot, I am just having trouble getting it exactly how I want. There are only a few tiny things I am having trouble with. I can't figure out how to get the triangle on the side of the bubble's border to be as thin as the rest of the bubble, as well as making it lower and smaller. I'm having trouble with positioning the sign in image a little lower like in the image of what I need it to look like. And lastly the "Sign In to Comment" needs to be a little to the left of the image. If anyone could shed any light on any of these things, it would be super appreciated!

Currently:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve:

[image]

As you can see I am very close! just a few tiny things giving me trouble.

HTML:

```
  <div class="sign-in">
    <div class="cell one">
      <p class="triangle-border right blue">Join the Conversation</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell two">
      <a href="#"><img class="sign-in-img" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/sign-in.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="si">Sign In to Comment</span>
```

CSS:

```
.triangle-border {
  position:relative;
  padding:15px;
  margin:1em 0 .5em;
  border:1px solid #5a8f00;
  color:#333;
  background:#fff;
  /* css3 */
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  min-width: 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
  background-color: #E0F6F2;
}

.triangle-border.blue {
  background-color: #CDE5F7;
  border:1px solid #3A7DBA;
}

.triangle-border.right {
  margin-right:30px;
}

.triangle-border:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-20px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
  left:40px; /* controls horizontal position */
  border-width:20px 20px 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#5a8f00 transparent;
  /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  display:block;
  width:0;
}

/* creates the smaller  triangle */
.triangle-border:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-13px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
  left:47px; /* value = (:before left) + (:before border-left) - (:after border-left) */
  border-width:13px 13px 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#fff transparent;
  /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  display:block;
  width:0;
}

/* creates the larger triangle */
.triangle-border.right:before {
  top:10px; /* controls vertical position */
  bottom:auto;
  left:auto;
  right:-30px; /* value = - border-left-width - border-right-width */
  border-width:15px 0 15px 30px;
  border-color:transparent #3A7DBA;
}

/* creates the smaller  triangle */
.triangle-border.right:after {
  top:16px; /* value = (:before top) + (:before border-top) - (:after border-top) */
  bottom:auto;
  left:auto;
  right:-21px; /* value = - border-left-width - border-right-width */
  border-width:9px 0 9px 21px;
  border-color:transparent #fff;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .sign-in {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table; 
  outline: none;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .sign-in .cell {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .sign-in .cell.one {
  width: 85%;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .sign-in .cell.two {
  padding-left: 2%;
  width: 15%;
}

.pagecontent span.si {
  font-size: .8em;
  color: #808C8D;
}
```

Comment: Have you examined the rendering in Chrome/Firefox developer tools? That is the place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="talk-bubble">
    talk bubble talk bubble talk bubble talk bubble talk bubble talk bubble talk bubble talk bubble talk bubble talk bubble talk bubble talk bubble talk bubble talk bubble
  </p>
  <p class="sign-in">
    Sign In to Comment
  </p>
  <img src="your/image.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: -2;
}

div.wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.sign-in {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding: 0;
}

p.talk-bubble {
  border: 1px solid #3A7DBA;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #CDE5F7;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

p.talk-bubble:before,
p.talk-bubble:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
}

p.talk-bubble:before {
  z-index: -1;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #3A7DBA;
  right: -12px;
  bottom: -1px;
}

p.talk-bubble:after {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #CDE5F7;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mcgraphix/zLx5967t/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```css
.triangle-border {
  position:relative;
  padding:15px;
  margin:1em 0 .5em;
  border:1px solid #5a8f00;
  color:#333;
  background:#fff;
  /* css3 */
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  min-width: 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
  background-color: #E0F6F2;
}

.triangle-border.blue {
  background-color: #CDE5F7;
  border:1px solid #3A7DBA;
}

.triangle-border.right {
  margin-right:30px;
}

.triangle-border:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-20px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
  left:40px; /* controls horizontal position */
  border-width:20px 20px 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#5a8f00 transparent;
  /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  display:block;
  width:0;
}

/* creates the smaller  triangle */
.triangle-border:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-13px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
  left:47px; /* value = (:before left) + (:before border-left) - (:after border-left) */
  border-width:13px 13px 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#fff transparent;
  /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  display:block;
  width:0;
}

/* creates the larger triangle */
.triangle-border.right:before {
  top:25px; /* controls vertical position */
  bottom:auto;
  left:auto;
  right:-15px; /* value = - border-left-width - border-right-width */
  border-width:5px 0 5px 15px;
  border-color:transparent #3A7DBA;
}

/* creates the smaller  triangle */
.triangle-border.right:after {
  top: 27px;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: -13px;
  border-width: 3px 0 3px 13px;
  border-color: transparent #ccf;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .sign-in {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table; 
  outline: none;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .sign-in .cell {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .sign-in .cell.one {
  width: 85%;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .sign-in .cell.two {
  padding-left: 2%;
  width: 15%;
}

.pagecontent span.si {
  font-size: .8em;
  color: #808C8D;
}
```

```html
<div class="sign-in">
  <div class="cell one">
    <p class="triangle-border right blue">Join the Conversation</p>
  </div>
</div>
```